# How to send XML PUT/POST request using AFNetworking 2.5

Tags: ios, swift, serialization, request, afnetworking

Can't figure out how I need to specify requestSerializer to send request in XML format. This is swift example:

```
var manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

manager.responseSerializer = AFXMLParserResponseSerializer()
manager.requestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()

var parameters = "<regNumber>123</regNumber><pinNumber>234</pinNumber>"
var encodingParameters = parameters.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding)

manager.PUT("serviceurl", parameters: encodingParameters, success: {
   //....
},
        failure: {
            ///.....
        }
)
```

You can see that now I am using AFHTTPRequestSerializer() - but I am not sure that is correct. Trying to find something similar to AFXMLParserResponseSerializer() but for request.

It works fine with AFJSONRequestSerializer, like this:

```
var manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

manager.responseSerializer = AFXMLParserResponseSerializer()
manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer(writingOptions: NSJSONWritingOptions()) 

var parameters = ["regNumber": 123, "pinNumber": 234]

manager.PUT("serviceurl", parameters: parameters, success: {
       //....
    },
            failure: {
                ///.....
            }
    )
```

Can anybody show working example with XML request using AFNetworking 2.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AFHTTPRequestOperation instead of AFHTTPRequestOperationManager like this:

```
    let xmlString = "<regNumber>123</regNumber><pinNumber>234</pinNumber>"
    let xmlData = xmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "serviceurl")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = xmlData

    let operation = AFHTTPRequestOperation(request: request);

    operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess({ (AFHTTPRequestOperation operation, AnyObject response) -> Void in
        //Response

    }, failure: { (AFHTTPRequestOperation operation, NSError    error) -> Void in
        println(error.localizedDescription)
    })
    operation.start()
```

Comment: Here is this answer in obj-c. It can be usefull for someone:

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    self.manager.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
    
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //Response
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure");
    }];
    [operation start];